# Meteor - Create a file to be downloaded (without triggering meteor to restart)

Tags: meteor

I want to create a file and then serve it using Meteor, but I don't want the server to restart when I create/update the file in the public directory.

The user will click on a button to create a config file on the server and I want the user to be able to download that config file.

Is there a way to do this without triggering the server to restart?

I have tried creating a link to the file and creating a hidden file but nothing has worked.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server restarts because you are running it in Development mode,
When it runs in production, it doesn't restart on content changes.

To run in production, only way I know is, after bundling application,
Have a look here: http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying

Comment: Thanks for the input.  It really is unfortunate that there isn't a way to somehow control the restart during development.

Answer (score 3):

Try `meteor run --production`. That might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't want to run in production mode, here is a workaround:

1. In order to prevent reloading, you have to generate your files in a folder that is located outside of your project's repository.
2. Then you will have your meteor app to serve the content of that folder.

Here is an example that uses the `connect` npm repository to make your local folder `/meteor/generated_files` served under the url `hostname.com/downloads/`:

```
var connect = Npm.require('connect');
var fs = Npm.require('fs');

function serveFolder(urlPath, diskPath){
    if(!fs.existsSync(diskPath))
        return false;
    RoutePolicy.declare(urlPath, 'network');
    WebApp.connectHandlers.use(urlPath, connect.static(diskPath));
    return true;
}

serveFolder('/downloads', '/meteor/generated_files/');
```

I [published](http://atmospherejs.com/package/static-server) the very primitive package I have that does just that.

Comment: what about the RoutePolicy & WebApp objects, where do they come from? My code crashes because they are not defined.

Comment: Good point !

You have to put this in a package and specify `api.use(['webapp', 'routepolicy'], 'server');` in `package.js`. 

I published my package that does just this (I edited my answer with the link).